# ASCII Animation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure what I'm missing here in my code. I can't get my clearTimeout to work... I keep getting an error saying myStopFunction() is not defined. Any ideas?
I've tried renaming it and checked to make sure that everything matches up, I'm just not sure why I keep getting this dang error!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ASCII Animations</title>
<h1> ASCII Animation Editor/Viewer </h1>
<br><h3> Jordan Keith: Linn-Benton Community College</h3>
<body>
<p> Enter the frams below, separated by "=====" 
<input onclick = "playAnimation();" type="button" id= "Play" value = "PLAY" />
<input onclick = "myStopFunction();" type="button" id= "Stop" value = "STOP" /></p>
<textarea id = "frameArea" cols="50" rows="30"></textarea>

<textarea id = "displayArea" cols="50" rows="30"></textarea>

<script src="ASCII.js"></script><br>

</form>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function playAnimation()
{
frameStr = document.getElementById("frameArea").value;

if(frameStr.indexOf("\r\n") !=-1)
{
    frameSeq = frameStr.split("=====\r\n");
}
else
{
    frameSeq = frameStr.split("=====\n");
}

currentFrame = 0;
showNextFrame();
}
var t;
function showNextFrame() 
{
document.getElementById("displayArea").value = frameSeq[currentFrame]

currentFrame = (currentFrame+1)% frameSeq.length;

t = setTimeout("showNextFrame();" , 250);
}

function myStopFuntion() 
{
clearTimeout(t);
}
```

Comment: Your javascript says `function myStopFuntion()`. You're missing a c in there.

Comment: _myStopFunction() is not defined_ - Sometimes (and I know it's rare in the world of computing!) it _is_ the simplest explanation that holds true ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your call for myStopFunction is missing a C in function.

```
clearInterval(t);
```

is what is used to clear the timer for Javascript

Answer (score 0):

`myStopFunction`  is not getting called due to a typo in function name.

Replace `function myStopFuntion()`  with `function myStopFunction()` .

Here is the running code:

```
<head>
<script>
function playAnimation() 
{
    frameStr = document.getElementById("frameArea").value;

    if (frameStr.indexOf("\r\n") != -1) {
        frameSeq = frameStr.split("=====\r\n");
    } else {
        frameSeq = frameStr.split("=====\n");
    }

    currentFrame = 0;
    showNextFrame();
}
var t;

function showNextFrame() 
{
    document.getElementById("displayArea").value = frameSeq[currentFrame];

    currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % frameSeq.length;

    t = setTimeout(showNextFrame, 250);

}

function myStopFunction() 
{
    alert("Stopping Now");
    clearTimeout(t);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input onclick="playAnimation();" type="button" id="Play" value="PLAY" />
    <input onclick="myStopFunction();" type="button" id="Stop" value="STOP" />
    <textarea id="frameArea" cols="50" rows="30"></textarea>
    <textarea id="displayArea" cols="50" rows="30"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
```

`JSFIDDLE LINK`: http://jsfiddle.net/52Nvj/4/